# Get parent function of closure

Tags: python, closures

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        pass

    return bar

inner_func = foo()
```

Is that somehow possible to get reference to parent function `foo` from `inner_func` or `bar`?

Looking into source code of `PythonTutorOnline` I found what I need [here](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/52f73531c2778e48a80ea765587372247988afeb/v3/pg_logger.py#L526). Is there any other approach to do that so? if not how I can get current stack info without using `Bdb`?

Comment: I think [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) might help. Try `inspect.stack()` in `bar`. (I am not quite sure tho)

Comment: @BhargavRao: I just tested it and you can get the *name* of `foo()`, but you can't get the actual function object.

Comment: @zondo How would you obtain the name? I posted an answer that relies on that.

Comment: @AlexHall: `inspect.stack()[0]` is the level where `inspect.stack()` is being called, so `inspect.stack()[1]` is the next level up: where `bar()` is called in `foo()`. .  That list is the frame, the file, the line number, _the function_, the actual code text, and some other number that always seems to be zero.  Therefore, to get the name, you use `inspect.stack()[1][3]` inside of `bar()`.  That will get the name `foo` because it is one up from `bar()`, but if you want it because it is one level lower than the module, use `inspect.stack()[-2][3]`.

Comment: @BhargavRao, that involves changing the function and calling the inner_func which I am not sure is what is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only find FunctionDef's inside the body of another function:

*test.py*:

```
def bar():
    pass

def foo():
    def bar():
        pass
    return bar

inner_func = foo()
```

Code:

```
import ast


def find_parent(par):
    for par_node in mod.body:
        if isinstance(par_node, ast.FunctionDef):
            for node in par_node.body:
                if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) and node.name == inner_func.func_name:     
                    return eval(par_node.name)
```

Output:

```
n [12]: from test import  *

In [13]: mod =  ast.parse(open("/home/padraic/test.py").read())

In [14]: find_parent(mod)
Out[14]: <function test.foo>

In [15]: find_parent(mod).func_name
Out[15]: 'foo'
```

Comment: If we have a previously function defined with same name as closure, it fails saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`.

Comment: @AdnanUmer, that is in the first line of my answer, are you open to using calling inner_func to get the parent?

Comment: No that is just a sample. In real that can be any closure and I've to figure out where that is actually defined.

Comment: @AdnanUmer, what do you mean  figure out where it is defined? What do you essentially want to do with it?

Comment: This is good enough but I was just think that each time I try to get parent function I'll get a different object.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm actually trying to implement [simple encoder](https://github.com/uadnan/PyTrace/blob/master/pytrace/encoders/builtins.py#L38) to encode `Function`. For that I need to know about parent of function to achieve two things 1) check function is closure or not 2) if so who is it's parent.

Comment: @AdnanUmer, defs are evaluated once so there is only one function object.

Answer (score 0):

It's far from perfect, but here's an idea:

`getattr(__import__(foo().__module__), 'foo')`

where the name `'foo'` can be obtained somehow according to a comment by @zondo.